# Error when there is no revision attribute for project

Tags: python

INPUT:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
<default revision="jb_2.5.4" remote="quic"/>
<project name="platform/vendor/google/proprietary/widevine"
         path="vendor/widevine"
         revision="refs/heads/jb_2.6"
         x-grease-customer="none"
         x-quic-dist="none"
         x-ship="none" />
<project path="external/dbus" name="platform/external/bus" revision="refs/heads/jb_2.5" x-ship="oss" x-quic-dist="la" x-grease-customer="none"/>

<project path="external/connectivity" name="platform/test/code" x-ship="oss" x-quic-dist="la" x-grease-customer="none"/>

</manifest>
```

Hi,

I have the following code which gets the revision value if it is present for the input shown above,if there is not "revision=" field it bails out with the error shown below..when there is no 
"revision=" tag I want to get the "default revsion" tag in the input..any inputs on how to do this withouth changing the existing functionality?

```
CODE:-

import shlex
import os
import sys
import json
import fileinput
import pwd
import itertools
import subprocess
import shutil
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

def manifest_data (name):
    print name
    pattern = re.compile('refs/heads/(.*)')
    tree = ET.parse('.repo/manifests/test.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    project = root.find("./project[@name='%s']" % name)
    print project
    if project != None:
        revision = project.get('revision')
        res = pattern.match(revision)
        return res.group(1)
    else:
        default = root.find("./default")
        return default.attrib.get('revision')

def main ():
    branch_name = "jb_mr2"
    print "branch_name"
    print branch_name
    projects = ['platform/vendor/google/proprietary/widevine','platform/external/bus','platform/test/code']
    #if os.path.isdir('.repo') :
        #print "Deleting .repo"
        #shutil.rmtree('.repo')
    RepoInitCmd =  'repo init -u git://git.quicinc.com/platform/manifest.git -b ' + branch_name
    proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(RepoInitCmd), stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, error = proc.communicate()
    for project in projects :
        branch = manifest_data(project)
        print branch

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ERROR:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "branch_manifest.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "branch_manifest.py", line 41, in main
    branch = manifest_data(project)
  File "branch_manifest.py", line 23, in manifest_data
    res = pattern.match(revision)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `manifest_data` as follow:

```
def manifest_data (name):
    ....
    if project != None:
        revision = project.get('revision')
        if revision:
            res = pattern.match(revision)
            return res.group(1)
    default = root.find("./default")
    return default.attrib.get('revision')
```