# Editing exported xml files and importing them into the same wiki

Tags: xml, mediawiki

I have used Special:Export to export a collection of articles from my own wiki install hosted on my local machine. I have made edits to each page in the file and want to import them back into the same wiki.

However, when I attempt to import them back into the same wiki using Special:Import, I get ‘No revisions imported’ for each page.

I found a very old post that suggested deleting the revision ID from each page in the XML file, but that didn’t help.

Then I tried changing the timestamp, but it’s taking much longer to import than it seems like it should & keeps timing out.

Any suggestions on what I need to do in order to reimport an exported XML file back into the same wiki?

This is a development wiki I'm using on my own laptop. I am the only user. I'm just creating content that will later be uploaded to my public wiki. I'm just trying to quickly edit a batch of pages. This seems like the easiest way, but maybe there is a better approach?

MediaWiki 1.39.4
PHP 7.4.33 (apache2handler)
MariaDB 10.4.27
Running on XAMPP for Windows

Comment: You are probably failing a schema test.  You need to add the revision.  He is a python example to add a default version : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247401/error-when-there-is-no-revision-attribute-for-project

Comment: You could try to delete the pages (see Extension:Nuke) in the wiki prior to importing their new versions.

Alsom you can use Special:ReplaceText from the extension ReplaceText to replace text.

Comment: I would suggest not to edit the xml dumps. instead there are some specific extensions that might help. Like PageSync (https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageSync) or PageExchange (https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Exchange).

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I’ll check them out tomorrow & see how I do.